# Django CKEditor Code Snippet not rendered correctly

Tags: python, django, ckeditor, code-snippets

I am building a Django blog that supports code snippets for both post and comments. The following is my CKEditor config in settings.py

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': 'full',
        'extraPlugins': ','.join(
            [
                'codesnippet',
                'widget',
                'dialog',
            ]),
    },
    'comment': {
        'toolbar_Full': [
            ['Styles', 'Format', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'SpellChecker', 'Undo', 'Redo'],
            ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor'],
            ['Image', 'Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule'],
            ['TextColor', 'BGColor'],
            ['Smiley', 'SpecialChar'], ['Source'],
            ['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock'],
            ['NumberedList','BulletedList'],
            ['Indent','Outdent'],
            ['Maximize'],
            ['CodeSnippet']
        ],
        'extraPlugins': ','.join(
            [
                'codesnippet',
                'widget',
                'dialog',
            ]),
    }
}
```

All instances of **RichTextField** in the models and forms are replaced with **RichTextUploadingField**. Then I ran the migrations.

My text field has the code snippet button. Clicking the button allows the end users to post code snippets.

[image: Code Snippet in Comment Form]

But when the form is submitted the snippet is not marked down correctly.

[image: Incorrect Markdown]

There are no markdown nor syntax highlighting. Am I missing something within the configs? Or does Django's form have limited support for code snippets?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use javascript library like highlight.js in your base.html   to make it like in ckedito

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.5.1/styles      /default.min.css">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.5.1   /highlight.min.js"></script>
 <script>hljs.highlightAll();</script>
```